# Java lightweight web client

Tags: java, playframework, web-client

My app is supposed to call a URL which would provide simple text data (1 or 0). The URL can be http/https and method is POST.

For example, my java app will call `https://web.address.com:1234/isActive` with some request parameter and then this URL would simply return **0 or 1** in text format.

What lightweight API should I use? Or can I use Play Framework's WS API only (not the whole framework)?

Answer (score 1):

For this "simple" task you can use Java's [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) classes from the standard library which are capable of connecting to a remote server and perform basic HTTP operations. Also know that [`URL.openConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection--) returns an [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instance with many helper/utility methods and constants regarding HTTP protocol.

Also see this excellent post which provides you more details and examples including performing an HTTP POST operation:

**[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)**

If you don't want to "do-it-yourself", there are numerous 3rd party libraries availabe (google it). To mention a few:

[Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (former [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/))

[Google HTTP Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client)